# The fundamental group of a loop space of any base point space $(X,x_0)$ is abelian?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was asked to prove that the fundamental group of a loop space of any base point space $(X, x_0)$ is abelian.

I thought that not every fundamental group of a base point space is abelian (for example, $S\vee S$, with the point that joins the two circles as the base point). Is the fundamental group of "loop space of a base point space $(X,x_0)$" not the same as the fundamental group of the base point space $(X,x_0)$? What am I missing?

Comment: $\Omega(X,x_0)$ is the space of all loops in $X$, topologized under the c-o topology.  This is not the same thing as $X$.  It is in fact a standard theorem that $\pi_1(\Omega(X))$ is abelian.

Comment: Ok got it. How might I go about proving the statement then?

Comment: Do you know the proof that $\pi_1(G)$ is abelian when $G$ is a topological group.  This is very nearly the same thing.  While $\Omega(X)$ is not a group, it is something very close called an $H$-group.

Comment: No I'd appreciate if you could explain further. I just started learning this.

Comment: This is a long story.  Have you searched this site for a duplicate?

Comment: For the proof that the fundamental group of a topological group is abelian, I came across a few posts. I haven't really processed it yet. And how does that relate to this problem?

Comment: Loop-product does not give a group structure, but it gives one up to homotopy.  This is good enough to prove your theorem.  You just mimic the proof for topl groups.  There are quicker ways to get it, but they're fancier.

Comment: How does it give a group structure up to homotopy? If you have time, it'd really help if you could flesh out the answers a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-space

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with basic facts about homotopy groups? The higher homotopy groups are all abelian. As well, there is an isomorphism between $[S^n , X]$ and $[S^{n-1},\Omega X]$ where the brackets denote based homotopy classes. This isomorphism is an example of the adjunction between reduced suspension and loop spaces that exists on the level of continuous maps and homotopy classes of maps.

These facts combined tell you that the fundamental group is abelian, though this proof does not work for a general H-space.

Answer (score 0):

This follow from the fact that$\pi_1(LM)=\pi_2(M)$ from the long exact sequence
associated to the fibration $ev_x:PM\rightarrow M$ whose fibre is $LM$, apply the Serre exact sequence and the fact that $\pi_2(M)$ is commutative.

Here $PM$ is the space of continuous map $c:[0,1]\rightarrow M, c(0)=x$ and $ev_x(c)=c(1)$. $PM$ is contractible, to see this consider $H_u(c)(t)=c(tu)$, $H_1$ is the identity and $H_0(c)$ is the constant path $c(t)=x$.

Comment: OP is a beginner and likely does not have fibration sequences.